# How should I approach authenticating a Google Cloud Function in my React application?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, graphql, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a React + GraphQL application that reaches out to a Google Cloud Function to run some code.  Currently I am allowing unauthenticated access, but I wish to lock it down.  I am not seeing how I can authenticate like this in my React application:

```
fetch("https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME", {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': access_token //  <-------- this is what I want
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(something)
})
```

This example was stated in this thread: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/775

I would love to authenticate with a service account, but I don't want to have to use a Node server.  Am I forced to go down the API key route?

This is the documentation for authenticating cloud functions:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't authenticate with a service account **from** your web or mobile app.  Giving up service account credentials to users of your app would be a massive security hole.  You should instead using something like Firebase Authentication as end-user auth, then provide the end-user credentials to the function to be validated.

Comment: I should have explained that I only mentioned the service account because my application will have/need credentials to reach out to the endpoint.  I do not have end-users that need to authenticate.

Comment: It's a security problem for your app (which is fully in the user's control) to receive a service account.  That opens an attack vector for anyone who cares to reverse engineer your app.  Just don't do it.

Comment: If the users can access to your endpoint without being authenticated, don't secure your Functions (but be careful to the cost!). Else, if you have user authenticated, I should have a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew that there should have been a better solution for my use-case.  API Gateway is new, so it was not coming up when I was looking for options.  Thank you for the responses.

https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use service account authentication from a web app. But if you would need to run this app locally for testing purposes, I would say you could use `google-auth-library`. More info and code examples can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users).

You would also need the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role for the service account you are using.

Having said this, I would advise you to offload your authentication to a dedicated authentication provider like Firebase authentication, Auth0, or Okta.